# How to inflate a gzip with a really old zlib?

Tags: gzip, zlib, deflate

I'm using a PPC platform that has an older version of zlib ported to it. Is it possible to use zlib 1.1.3 to inflate an archive made with gzip 1.5?

```
$ gzip --list --verbose vmlinux.z
method  crc     date  time           compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
defla 12169518 Apr 29 13:00             4261643             9199404  53.7% vmlinux
```

The first 32 bytes of the archive are

```
00000000  1f 8b 08 08 29 f4 8a 60  00 03 76 6d 6c 69 6e 75  |....)..`..vmlinu|
00000010  78 00 ec 9a 7f 54 1c 55  96 c7 6f 75 37 d0 fc 70  |x....T.U..ou7..p|
```

I've tried using this code (where source is a pointer to the first byte at `1f 8b`) with the three options A, B, and C for the WBIT initialization.

```
int ZEXPORT gunzip (dest, destLen, source, sourceLen)
    Bytef *dest;
    uLongf *destLen;
    const Bytef *source;
    uLong sourceLen;
{
    z_stream stream;
    int err;

    stream.next_in = (Bytef*)source;
    stream.avail_in = (uInt)sourceLen;
    /* Check for source > 64K on 16-bit machine: */
    if ((uLong)stream.avail_in != sourceLen) return Z_BUF_ERROR;

    stream.next_out = dest;
    stream.avail_out = (uInt)*destLen;
    if ((uLong)stream.avail_out != *destLen) return Z_BUF_ERROR;

    stream.zalloc = (alloc_func)my_alloc;
    stream.zfree = (free_func)my_free;

    /* option A */
    err = inflateInit(&stream);
    /* option B */
    err = inflateInit2(&stream, 15 + 16);
    /* option C */
    err = inflateInit2(&stream, -MAX_WBITS);
 
    if (err != Z_OK) return err;

    err = inflate(&stream, Z_FINISH);
    if (err != Z_STREAM_END) {
        inflateEnd(&stream);
        return err == Z_OK ? Z_BUF_ERROR : err;
    }
    *destLen = stream.total_out;

    err = inflateEnd(&stream);
    return err;
}
```

### Option A:

zlib inflate() fails with error Z_DATA_ERROR. "unknown compression method"

```
z_stream.avail_in  = 4261640
z_stream.total_in  = 1
z_stream.avail_out = 134152192
z_stream.total_out = 0
```

### Option B:

zlib inflateInit2_() fails at line 118 with a Z_STREAM_ERROR.

```
  /* set window size */
  if (w < 8 || w > 15)
  {
    inflateEnd(z);
    return Z_STREAM_ERROR;
  }
```

### Option C:

zlib inflate() fails with error Z_DATA_ERROR. "invalid block type"

```
z_stream.avail_in  = 4261640
z_stream.total_in  = 1
z_stream.avail_out = 134152192
z_stream.total_out = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your option B would work for zlib 1.2.1 or later.

With zlib 1.1.3, there are two ways.

1. Use the `gzopen()`, `gzread()`, and `gzclose()` to read the gzip stream from a file and decompress into memory.
2. To decompress from the gzip stream in memory, use your option C, raw inflate, *after* manually decoding the gzip header. Use `crc32()` to calculate the CRC-32 of the decompressed data as you inflate it. When the inflation completes, manually decode the gzip trailer, checking the CRC-32 and size of the decompressed data.

Manual decoding of the gzip header and trailer is simple to implement. See [RFC 1952](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1952) for the description of the header and trailer.